# Gap between header and height issue. (Outlook 2013)

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I am experience a gap between the header and the body only in Outlook 2013. Below is a screen-shot to hot it looks in outlook:

[image]

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

My header HTML code:

```
<!-- start header -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="580" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif"   >
    <tr>
        <td width="241" height="51" valign="top" height="51" style="line-height: 51px;">
            <img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/logo.png" style="display:block;">
        </td>
        <td width="179" height="51" valign="top" bgcolor="#00b0ed" style="background:#00b0ed;" style="line-height: 51px;" ></td>
        <td width="1" height="51" valign="top" style="line-height: 51px;" ></td>
        <td width="159" height="51" valign="top" style=" text-align:center; font-size:14px; " style="line-height: 51px;" >
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  width="159" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align:center;"  border="0" height="51">
                <tr>    
                    <td width="159" align="left" valign="top" height="12" style="line-height:12px;" ><img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/invitation.png" style="display:block;" height="12"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  width="159" align="left" valign="top"  style="background:#00B0ED;" > <img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/blank.png" style="display:block;" height="5"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  width="159" align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:center; background:#00B0ED; " height="26" > <a href="#" style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:100; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:14px "><span style="color:#fff; text-decoration:none; font-weight:100; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; text-align:center; font-size:14px ">INVITATION</span></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td  width="159" align="left" valign="top"  style="background:#00B0ED;" > <img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/blank.png" style="display:block;" height="8"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="left" valign="top" colspan="4" height="1"><img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford/images/blank.jpg" height='1' width="1" style="display:block;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- end header -->
```

Comment: Your image tags are not closed and could be the problem. This is how they are, `<img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/logo.png" style="display:block;">` and this is how it should be, `<img src="http://limus.dev.limusdesign.com/fordfoundation/emails/ford-invitation-template/logo.png" style="display:block;" />`. Let me know if that did anything.

Comment: No, no luck. It seems to only be happening in Outlook 2013.

Comment: Hmm, the bad news is outlook has horrible html support and I'm guessing it has to be an un-closed tag or something with the styles.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably help:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3795/outlook-2013-says-no-to-empty-table-cells

Basically, it's a padding issue with outlook - and it's related to font sizing. That's quite an old problem from waaaay back in the day of table based website layouts and the old tricks of setting font size to 1px, or using nasty old 1x1px transparent gif files :)

Comment: @Shivam Outlook has a minimum cell/row height of 19px. Either try this technique or design around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your stylesheet

```
table { border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt;}
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

And inline for each table declare

```
table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```

To get the 1 pixel white space between each cell use nested tables. and declare the table like so

```
table border="1" border-color="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
```